# analytics package for laravel 5.2 record country wise

Tags: laravel

I tried package for analytics package for laravel 5.2 but any package not working properly .i want record country wise..

please suggest any package .thank you

Comment: You want to track what country the visitors on your website are from?

Comment: i want to see about my users that are registered country wise .. i want to see  all users detail that are using or visiting on business .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this package . It will be show you country wise records.

```
https://github.com/ipunkt/laravel-analytics
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using google analytics to track your status then I suggest following laravel package

```
composer require spatie/laravel-analytics
```